# Upsample a graph and preserve the information

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, regression

I have various length of time series data. Therefore I need to normalize it to be the same length first.

For example  data_1 has 200 points with this shape

[image: data_1]

data_2 has 7000 points with this shape

[image: data_2]

data_3 has 3000 points

[image: data_3]

I had checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435868/how-to-fit-data-and-then-sample-from-the-fitted-function-to-draw-curve). It does not work with my pulse shape. I lost significant information

**Question:**
How can I upsample to 9000 points and preserve the shape of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [numpy's interp function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) does what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x1)

x2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 30)
y2 = np.interp(x2, x1, y1)
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x2, y2, '.')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot from example program]